# Finding the max in an R vector using a for loop, without using max()

Tags: r

How do I find the max in an R vector using a for loop, without using max()?

Here is my solution:

```
a=c(-9,20,40,1,5,0)
y=-Inf
z=0

for (i in a) {
x=i
if(x>y){y=i}
else{y=Inf}
if(y!=-Inf & z<y){z=i}
}
print(paste0("maximum number is:" , z))
```

Is there a simpler way to do it?

Comment: Why no `max()` ? Is there something specific that you are trying to achieve? Not even `which.max()` ?

Comment: Well, its an assignment, which specifically said don't use any function that directly finds the max.

Comment: I just deleted my response. You should NOT be posting an assignment question. You will miss out on the benefit of the learning experience. Try to think through what you are currently doing and see if you can come up with a simpler solution on your own.

Comment: So if this is an assignment why are you posting this here? Who is it going to be useful to reading about incorrect practices of finding a max in R? Future cheaters?

Comment: @JPC - Half of the questions on this site are assignment questions.  At least he is being honest about it.  It is not against SO guidelines to ask questions about your work.

Comment: Well, literately day 1 in school, nothing taught yet. Just basing on previous class's experience.

Comment: @RichardScriven really? Perhaps I'm being naive then...

Comment: HW questions are ok (if you are up front about them being HW), but the question also needs to be a good question for StackOverflow. Finding the max value in a numeric vector with dumb and arbitrary restrictions like not using `max` serves no purpose for the larger community, and hence it is not a good or useful question.

Comment: @RichardScriven to be fair, it might not be against SO guidelines (not sure...I don't usually read those, but I'll take your word for it), but I think it's common sense that education is pointless if you don't actually do the work on your own...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP question was "can this be done on a simpler way", and not "do it for me", so the answer will be, yes it can be done in a simpler way, without sploiling the fun :)

## Step 1

Start by writing a new version without using the `x` variable (use `i` directly)

## Step 2

Rename your variables to things that make sense!
When you start writing code, use long names variables.

Do not call them `i`, `x`, `y`, etc...

Call them `current_value`, `maximum_value_seen`, `current_index`, ...

## Step 3

The second `if()` that you wrote, only executes when the first `if()` is `TRUE`

So you can rewrite your code from this:

```
# if1
if(x>y){y=i}
else{y=Inf}

# if2
if(y!=Inf){z=i}
```

To this

```
# if1
if(x>y){
    y=i
    # if2
    if(y!=Inf){z=i}
}
else{y=Inf}
```

## Step 4

The second if (`#if2`) is now useless!
Remove it

## Step 5

The `y` variable is also useless, you can remove it now.

## Step 6

Enjoy your hard work, with your new *4-5 lines* max function and go grab a beer (you're a student after all!)

Comment: Thanks alot for the tips. I see that the second if can be integrated to the first if so it won't run every time. I only took a introductory to CS a long time ago, now coming back for BioStatistics.

Comment: Ahh, my bad, it should be: else{y=-Inf}

Comment: Are you sure? rename your variables to stop mixing `x`, `y` etc in your head, and just keep the current maximum